# How to modify FFmpegFrameRecorder.java in javacv to support audio sample rate change?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, javacv

I want to know if ffmpeg port from javacv supports audio sample rate change, and if so, I would need some guidelines for changing FFmpegFrameRecorder.java to support it.

Comment: Anyone who ever wanna know about,How to play the grabbed audio frame from FrameGrabber.

One may look at my blog,Clearly posted what you want,

http://revealedtricks4u.blogspot.in/2015/03/play-audio-sample-grabbed-using-javacv.html

Regards,
Shihab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it supports. Care should be taken in FFmpegFrameRecorder.java that SwrContext object is correctly configured and that the number of samples provided to avcodec_fill_audio_frame(..) match the codec input frame size.

Comment: Anyone who ever wanna know about,How to play the grabbed audio frame from FrameGrabber.

One may look at my blog,Clearly posted what you want,

http://revealedtricks4u.blogspot.in/2015/03/play-audio-sample-grabbed-using-javacv.html

Regards,
Shihab